# "Zoom", "pan" and "tilt" in HTML5 similar to a Prezi presentation

Tags: html, prezi

I want to make a landing page similar to a **Prezi** presentation, with automatic zoom tilt and pan features. Could you point me to something thing similar so that I can work on it?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to get jiggy with the zoom, you should be peeping: http://jaukia.github.io/zoomooz/  That is wayyy more fun than impress.js for reppin' the Prezi

Answer (score 1):

There is also [Strut](http://strut.io) which is a GUI for authoring impress.js presentations.  Here is a demo video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zA5s8wwme44

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [layerJS](http://layerjs.org), an open source library which can create **Prezi-like** HMTL5 web interfaces. You can define **neighborship** of frames which enables touch and mouse **gestures** to transition between frames. It even allows **multiple layers** if you need some elements to move independently of each other.

It's super **simple**: just add a **stage** div put one or more layers in and add as many **frames** as you want between you can have **zooming, panning and rotating transitions**.

There is more than just Prezi like transitions by using a different layer layout type than "canvas". Just have a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/layerJS/layerJS/wiki).

The HTML code would look like this:

```
<div data-wl-type="stage">
  <div data-wl-type="layer" data-wl-layout-type="canvas">
    <div data-wl-type="frame" data-wl-name="frame1" data-wl-x="100" data-wl-width="1000" data-wl-rotation="45" ...>
    </div>
    <div data-wl-type="frame" data-wl-neighbors-l="frame1" ...>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that's a bit too late for a timely answer, but you can try [Impress.js](http://bartaz.github.com/impress.js/#/bored).

Answer (score 0):

There is now [Webpgr](http://webpgr.com). It's an Photoshop-like online editor for exactly creating zooming panning and tilting landing pages.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called impress.js (http://bartaz.github.io/impress.js/#/bored) that is very cool to achieve what you want.

Check up the page, you'll see that is a demo itself (and don't forget to see the source, documentation is there).

Hope this might help you, anything please let me know.